# Is there any possibility to use Bittorrent protocol for streaming video via flash or html5 video player?

Tags: flash, streaming, html5-video, bittorrent

Is there any possibility to use Bittorrent protocol (or another p2p) for streaming video via flash or html5 video player embedded into web site page? Preferable via html5 video plyaer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> html5

In the specific case of html5 it is not possible to implement existing p2p protocols since web APIs do not provide access to raw TCP or UDP sockets.

There are websockets and the webrtc protocol which provide p2p connections, but they layer additional protocols ontop of the underlying network sockets and thus cannot be used to talk to software using other protocols.

Privileged code in browsers (i.e. extensions/addons) may provide access to proper sockets and thus could be used to implement clients for existing p2p protocols.

But bittorrent can transfer all kinds of video contents, .mkv is a popular container for example. Web browsers are less powerful than dedicated media players and may not be able to decode some videos.

Ontop of that streaming is possible via bittorrent but it goes against one of its design goals (the rarest-first policy).

So it's possible if you're willing to write browser extensions, but in my opinion you would end up with a piece of software that can do less than existing, dedicated solutions (i.e. a bittorrent client + a media player).

Answer (score 0):

[Tribler](http://www.tribler.org/) is an open-source project that uses the BitTorrent protocol.
However the demos were using SwarmPlayer on the client side. You can get more info on their site. See also the [streaming experiment](https://www.tribler.org/StreamingExperiment/).

[GoalBit](http://goalbit-solutions.com/community/open_source_downloads) is another P2P open-source project which uses something similar to BitTorrent. The [demo](http://trial.goalbit-solutions.com/goalbit-misc/gpa/play/bigbangtheory) works with JWPlayer.

Just do a web search since there are many other projects. You can also find paid solutions like [Streamroot](http://www.streamroot.io/demo?url=http%3A%2F%2Fakamai.streamroot.edgesuite.net%2Fvodorigin%2Ftos.mp4%2Fmanifest.mpd) to name one.